# JaCoCo coverage report in sonarqube with github workflow

Tags: maven, sonarqube, github-actions

I am trying to setup sonar pipleline using github workflows. My pom.xml has the below plugin configured in build:

`pom.xml`

```
<!-- Dependencies needed for creating SonarQube coverage reports -->
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
               <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>prepare-agent</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
                   <execution>
                       <id>report</id>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>report</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
```

When I do a mvn clean install I can find the jacoco.xml on the path: `target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml`

Next I have setup my workflow .yml file under `.github/workflows/main.yml`

`main.yml`

```
    jobs:
      maven-build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          - name: Set up JDK 11
            uses: actions/setup-java@v3
            with:
              java-version: '11'
              distribution: 'temurin'
              cache: maven
          - name: Build with Maven
            run: mvn clean install
      sonar_analysis:
        needs: maven-build
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - name: Analyze with SonarCloud         
            uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action@de2e56b42aa84d0b1c5b622644ac17e505c9a049
            env:
              GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information
              SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}   # Generate a token on Sonarcloud.io, add it to the secrets of this repo with the name SONAR_TOKEN (Settings > Secrets > Actions > add new repository secret)
            with:
              args:             
                -Dsonar.projectKey=sk-Prices-Tracker
                -Dsonar.organization=sk
```

The `maven-build` job does a clean install which generates the `jacoco.xml` report. Next the
`sonar_analysis` runs after `maven-build` is run to ensure that the report exists before sonar scanning runs.

On the workflow run log I can see that it is unable to pick up the `jacoco.xml` report. What am I doing wrong here?

```
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=10ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jobs are run independently on different (virtual) machines.

Therefore, if you want to access artefacts from `maven-build` in `sonar_analysis`, you need to either use the action [upload-artifact](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) or join your two jobs into one like so:

```yaml
    jobs:
      maven-build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v3
          - name: Set up JDK 11
            uses: actions/setup-java@v3
            with:
              java-version: '11'
              distribution: 'temurin'
              cache: maven
          - name: Build with Maven
            run: mvn clean install

          - name: Analyze with SonarCloud         
            uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action@de2e56b42aa84d0b1c5b622644ac17e505c9a049
            env:
              GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information
              SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}   # Generate a token on Sonarcloud.io, add it to the secrets of this repo with the name SONAR_TOKEN (Settings > Secrets > Actions > add new repository secret)
            with:
              args:             
                -Dsonar.projectKey=sk-Prices-Tracker
                -Dsonar.organization=sk
```

Comment: Thank you! After I changed it as you suggested I got another error - 

`Maven project detected. You should run the goal 'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar' during build rather than using this GitHub Action.`

I simplified my job further and modified run as

`mvn clean install -e -X sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io -Dsonar.login=${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }} -Dsonar.projectKey=sk-Prices-Tracker -Dsonar.organization=sk` 

and removed the Analyze with SonarCloud step entirely